# Excel find date difference between minimum and maximum date in month

Tags: excel, date, sum, max, difference

I'm trying to fix up a formula I have that's having some issues. It's supposed to track # days invoiced in a month, so the high-level idea is to take the maximum date in a month and subtract the minimum date in the month, and on error subtract the 1st day of the month. My current formula has issues adjust for invoices that may cross months, an example being 1/25 - 2/3 where if this were the only invoice, January should show 7 days invoiced and February would show 3. If there were another invoice from 2/15 - 2/28, I would want Feb to show the maxed invoice days, 14 in this example.

For reference here's what a table could look like:

```
 A              B           C                D                 E       F 
 start month    end month   invoice begin    invoice end       Month   Max Days invoiced
 jan 1          feb 1       1/25/14          2/3/14            1/1     7
 feb 1          feb 1       2/15/14          2/28/14           2/1     14
                                                               3/1
                                                               etc.........
```

I tried the formula below but it was erroring out, plus I don't think it will account for gaps in invoices like in my example.:

```
=IF(B2:B100=X1,MAX(D2:D100),) - IF(A2:A100=X2,MIN(C2:C100),A2)
'where column X is a list of months, X1 = 1/1, X2 = 2/1, etc.
```

No luck with this formula either, keeps erroring out and giving 0 values:

```
{=DATEDIF(IF(A2:A100=E2,MIN(C2:C100),),IF(B2:B100=E2,MAX(D2:D100),),"d")}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: So inputs would be columns A - D in the above example, and results would be days invoiced by month, say in column E & F (adding above).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but you could probably make use of the EOMONTH() function. Here's an example of it:

```
=EOMONTH(A2,0)-A2+1
```

[image: Example1]

by the way - here is how you would get the start of the month:

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1
```

Try the following per your comment below:
"I think this could be useful but I'm not sure it would work if the invoice end was, say, 2/21 or anytime before the EOM"

```
=IF(B3>=EOMONTH(A3,0),EOMONTH(A3,0)-A3+1,B3-A3+1)
```

[image: Example2]

Comment: I think this could be useful but I'm not sure it would work if the invoice end was, say, 2/21 or anytime before the EOM

Comment: this is super awesome for individual invoices and tracking days invoiced for the invoice begin month, but I'm trying to collect the largest amount of days invoiced for each month from multiple invoices per month, if that makes sense.

Comment: @IanSchneider I'm not sure what "the largest amount of days invoiced for each month from multiple invoices per month" means. Do you mean you want a total for Jan, Feb, Mar etc - that lists the total number of days all your invoice date ranges overlap with each month. It does seem a little outside the scope of your original question - so I'll probably call it quits here - but good luck.